# How to replicate (this) specific Android constraint layout on Flutter

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I want to find a solution to mimic attached image Android contraint layout on a Flutter wrapped widgets structure.

In this case, blue text TextView width is wrap content and image (dollar sign) must take same width.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

[image: Constraint behavior I want on Flutter]

This is my current code, a simple column, I tried a lot of alternatives but I can't figure it out logically :/

```
  Widget _getPublisherLogoImage() {
    return ClipOval(
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: _publisherLogo,
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getNewsItemHour(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
        child: Text(DateUtils.getHoursMinutesStringDate(_timestamp),//'09:35',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
    );
  }

  Widget _getNewsItemQuotation() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
        child: Text('\$$_price',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
    );
  }

.
. 
.
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    _getPublisherLogoImage(),
    _getNewsItemHour(context),
    _getNewsItemQuotation()
  ],
)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Share your code what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, code shared. My current aproach is set a fixed size to image widget, tried a lot of alternatives but I cant figure out how set that relationship between those two widgets

Answer (score 0):

To match the text to the image, I use a technique where an `IntrinsicWidth` widget wraps a `Column`, whose `crossAxisAlignment` is stretched.

Change the image width in the code from `width: 200` to whatever you want, and the text underneath will match its size.

P.S. The second text widget at the bottom of the screen scales to the screen size.

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Replicate Android Layout',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Replicate Android Layout')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IntrinsicWidth(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _getPublisherLogoImage(),
                  FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, child: _getNewsItemHour(context)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            _getNewsItemQuotation(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _getPublisherLogoImage() {
  return Image(
    image: NetworkImage(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl.jpg'),
    width: 200,
  );
}

Widget _getNewsItemHour(BuildContext context) {
  return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Text('09.35',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)));
}

Widget _getNewsItemQuotation(BuildContext context) {
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double _price = 60.59;
  return Text(
    '\$$_price',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: width * 0.25,
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
  );
}
```

Run in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5b207c8287b946deace31d8c5e85edea&null_safety=true).